# Numbering order in IUPAC name of a trisubstituted alkatriene

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

During E/Z-nomenclature class, I found this molecule.

[image: bond-line representation of molecule under this question]

Using [*MarvinSketch*](https://chemaxon.com/products/marvin) 21.15.0 version I have **(3*E*,5*E*)-6-bromo-3,4-dimethylhexa-1,3,5-triene** for it. Why the name couldn't be **(1*E*,3*E*)-1-bromo-3,4-dimethylhexa-1,3,5-triene**? What I missing?

Comment: The name (1E,3E)-1-bromo-3,4-dimethylhexa-1,3,5-triene is correct. Therefore, it's hard to answer why MarvinSketch shows a different name; at least this is not because of any particular IUPAC rule.

Comment: Another question about problems with tie-breaking rules in MarvinSketch: [What are the preferred IUPAC names of these two compounds?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/90906/103369)