# Choosing Parent Chain, Complexity of Side Chains

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, hydrocarbons

Which parent chain should we choose for this structure? is it A or B?

[image]

I followed the rule [A-2.6](https://www.acdlabs.com/IUPAC/nomenclature/79/r79_36.htm), but it still got me confused.
Both alternative A and B has the same number of side chains (2 side chains) - rule A-2.6(a).
Both alternative A and B has the same number of locants, which are 5 and 6 - A-2.6(b).
Both alternative A and B has the same number of carbon in each locants, which are 4 atoms on number 5 and 9 atoms on number 6 - A-2.6(c).
Both alternative A and B branched side chains are quite similar, how do we decide? - A-2.6(d)

Comment: Note that your link points to obsolete IUPAC recommendations from 1979.

Comment: Related: [IUPAC naming - choosing the main branch](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/22367/7951)

Answer (score 3):

You have already reduced the problem to two possible parent chains:
**A:** 5-(2-methylpropyl)-6-(3-methyloctan-4-yl)dodecane
or
**B:** 5-(butan-2-yl)-6-(2-methyloctan-4-yl)dodecane

In order to identify the preferred name, we have to read further in the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069)*. In particular, the following potentially relevant rules are actually not helpful in this case:

- P-45.2.1 maximum number of substituents cited as prefixes
- P-45.2.2 the lower locant set for substituent groups cited as prefixes
- P-45.2.3 the lower locant set for substituent groups in order of citation

However, we finally find:

> **P-45.5.1** The preferred IUPAC name is the name that is earlier in alphanumerical order (see P-14.5). Alphabetic letters are considered first in the order that they appear in the name; all Roman letters are considered before any italic letters, unless the latter are used as locants or are a part of a compound or composite locant, for example, ‘*N*’ and ‘4a’. Then, if still there is a choice, numerical locants are considered in the order of their appearance in the name.

Therefore, the preferred name is **5-(butan-2-yl)-6-(2-methyloctan-4-yl)dodecane** since ‘butan-yl’ is earlier alphabetically than ‘methylpropyl’.